Difference between requests and urllib
UPD: no, the linked question is not the same and doesn't answer mine (unless i'm illiterate).
it's more of a surface question on why there are so many request-making libraries in python and which one to use. i'm fully aware of the options and my question is a little more specific
What is the difference in requests between the requests module and the urllib module?
For testing purposes, i'm sending a GET request to
https://www.securityweek.com/
with just a user-agent header.
urllib gets the correct page as a response while requests gets a response with "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue"
Here are the examples:
using requests:
import requests


url = 'https://www.securityweek.com/'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('test1.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(response.text)

using urllib:
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


url = 'https://www.securityweek.com/'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = urlopen(Request(url, headers=headers))
with open('test2.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

I've tried checking with tools like httpbin but as far as I can see they should be the same.

This question is similar to: What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, urllib3 and requests module?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@folengateis if you read the question I asked fully, it's pretty clear of what the difference is, and that the ansers to that one don't answer this one

requests typically uses urllib underneath, but it tends to provide an easier to use API when sending requests to an endpoint.
Regarding your question, neither requests nor urllib execute Javascript (Selenium could be picked for this because it uses a literal web driver), but it might differ on how those two actually bypass bot detection systems in various websites.
requests automatically sends a default set of headers, including User-Agent, Accept-Encoding and Detection, which could trigger those bot systems and block the further interaction with the web server. Keep-Alive & Connection Pooling doesn't help either.
More specific differences between the two can be found on this topic on the website.

i am fully aware that requests uses urllib, and also of selenium. i'm interested specifically in differences in http requests, that the libraries mentioned make which result in the specified behaviour. from what i saw using httpbin the only different headers were Accept and Accept-Encoding, both of which didn't make a difference .
Could you elaborate on the Detection header?

@andy it's a subjective matter of how bot detection systems work. Each of them are implemented differently and make use of the headers you are sending through the requests. Please read the third paragraph from my answer.

the question is not about the bot detection systems, it's about the difference in requests. please read my comment
